# How to create a .bmp in WinCE

Tags: c++, image-processing, windows-ce, bmp

I have a camera that returns raw images that can easily be converted to a bitmap that can be saved to a file by the following C# method (that I did not write). From various sources, I have determined that the pictures have 8 bits per pixel, and may or may not be grayscale.

```
private void rawImgToBmp(byte[] imgData, String fname) {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), 
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            { bmp.Palette.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(255, i, i, i); }
        //Copy the data from the byte array into the bitmap
        BitmapData bmpData = 
            bmp.LockBits( new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                          ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
        Marshal.Copy(imgData, 0, bmpData.Scan0, getWidth() * getHeight());
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData); //Unlock the pixels
        bmp.Save(FileName);
    }
```

My question is: how would I go about writing the equivalent method in C++, using built in functions of Windows CE 4.2?

erisu: thanks for the palette code, I think it's right. I've resorted to filling in the rest of the structs manually, according to the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that works for me. It is based on erisu's answer and [Wikipedia's description of the BMP format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format). For anyone else using this answer, I recommend that you understand the BMP format as fully as possible, so you can adjust the header fields accordingly.

The complicated loop at the end is my workaround for an issue with my hardware/OS, where it would not write all of the data I supplied to fwrite. It should work in any environment, though.

```
#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER > 1000

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define NPAL_ENT 256

INT WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPTSTR lpCmdLine,
                    INT nShowCmd )
{
    int w = 1920, h = 1080; // My values, yours may vary

//////////////////////// File Operations ///////////////////////////////

    // Reading raw img
    FILE* f = fopen("\\FlashDisk\\raw_img.bin","r");
    if(NULL == f){printf("BAD");exit(1);}

    // Obtaining size of raw img
    fseek (f , 0L , SEEK_END);
    DWORD fsize = (DWORD)ftell (f);
    fseek (f , 0L , SEEK_SET);

    char *imgData = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*fsize);
    if(NULL == imgData) {printf("NOT imgData");exit(2);}

    // Copy contents of file into buffer
    DWORD result = fread(imgData,1,fsize,f);
    if (result != fsize) {
        printf ("Reading error. Expected: %d, Got: %d\n",fsize, result ); 
        if(ferror(f)){printf("An error: %d\n", ferror(f)); }
        if(feof(f)) {printf("EOF\n");}
        delete[] imgData;
        fclose(f);
        exit (3);
    }
    fclose(f);

//////////////////////// BMP Operations ///////////////////////////////

    /* A bitmap has the following components:
     *  1. BMP file header
     *  2. Bitmap Information (DIB) header
     *  3. Color Palette
     *  4. Raw Data
     */
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;
    ZeroMemory( &bmfh, sizeof( bmfh ) );
    bmfh.bfType = 0x4D42; // Magic #
    bmfh.bfSize = sizeof( bmfh ) + sizeof( BITMAPINFOHEADER )
        + NPAL_ENT*sizeof(PALETTEENTRY) + w*h; // Or total file size if w/h not known
    bmfh.bfOffBits = sizeof( bmfh ) + sizeof( BITMAPINFOHEADER )
        + NPAL_ENT*sizeof(PALETTEENTRY);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih;
    ZeroMemory( &bmih, sizeof( bmih ) );
    bmih.biWidth = w;
    bmih.biHeight = h;
    bmih.biSize = sizeof(bmih);
    bmih.biPlanes = 1;
    bmih.biBitCount = 8;
    bmih.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmih.biSizeImage = w * h;

    int palSize = NPAL_ENT*sizeof(PALETTEENTRY);
    LOGPALETTE *logpal=(LOGPALETTE*)new BYTE[sizeof(LOGPALETTE)+palSize];
    if(!logpal) {delete [] imgData; printf("!logpal\n"); exit(4);}
    logpal->palVersion=0x300;
    logpal->palNumEntries=NPAL_ENT;
    int i=0;
    do {  // Exact palette format varies. This is what worked for me
        logpal->palPalEntry[i].peRed=i;
        logpal->palPalEntry[i].peGreen=i;
        logpal->palPalEntry[i].peBlue=i;
        logpal->palPalEntry[i].peFlags=NULL;
    } while(++i<NPAL_ENT);

    // Complete bitmap is now in memory, time to save it
    TCHAR bmpfname[80];
    wsprintf( bmpfname, (TCHAR*) TEXT( "\\USBDisk\\out.bmp" ) );

    // open the file for writing
    FILE *bmpFile = _wfopen(bmpfname,L"wb"); 
    if(!bmpFile) { delete[] imgData; delete[] logpal; exit(6); }

    // write the bitmap to file, in whatever chunks WinCE allows
    size_t totWrit = 0, offset = 0, writeAmt = 0;
    while(totWrit < bmfh.bfSize){
        if(totWrit < sizeof(bmfh)){ // File header
            offset = totWrit;
            totWrit += fwrite( ((char*)&bmfh)+offset, 1, sizeof(bmfh)-offset, bmpFile );
        }
        else if(totWrit<sizeof(bmfh)+sizeof(bmih)){ // Image header
            offset = totWrit - sizeof(bmfh);
            totWrit += fwrite( ((char*)&bmih)+offset, 1, sizeof(bmih)-offset, bmpFile );
        }
        else if(totWrit<sizeof(bmfh)+sizeof(bmih)+palSize) { // Pallette
            offset = totWrit - sizeof(bmfh) - sizeof(bmih);
            totWrit += fwrite( ((char*)&logpal->palPalEntry)+offset, 1, palSize-offset, bmpFile );
        }
        else { // Image data
            offset = totWrit - sizeof(bmfh) - sizeof(bmih) - palSize;
            if(bmfh.bfSize-totWrit >= IO_SIZE) {
                writeAmt = IO_SIZE;
            }
            else {
                writeAmt = bmfh.bfSize-totWrit;
            }
            totWrit += fwrite( &imageBuffer[offset], 1, writeAmt, bmpFile );
        }

        // Close and open after each iteration to please WinCE
        fflush(bmpFile);
        fclose(bmpFile);
        Sleep(4000); 
        bmpFile = _wfopen(bmpfname,L"ab");
        if(!bmpFile) {flog->lprintf("Couldn't reopen bmpfile"); delete [] logpal; return 0;}
    }
    fclose(bmpFile);

    if(totWrit != bmfh.bfSize) {
        printf("BMP Size mismatch: %d/%d.",totWrit,bmfh.bfSize);
        delete [] imgData;
        delete [] logpal;
        exit(-1);
    }
   // Cleanup
    delete [] imgData;
    delete [] logpal;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I wonder if the problem is the second parameter to fopen? You only specify "r", but the file is obviously binary. Try "rb"

Answer (score 1):

Typically I use CreateBitmap or CreateCompatibleBitmap to generate bitmaps in windows. I am unfamiliar with WinCE but the functions seem to be present. Your data looks to be in 8 bit per pixel with a 256 color palette so you will also most likely need CreatePalette, SelectPalette, and RealizePalette functions.

Something like (warning: untested code):

```
HBITMAP hBmp=CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, 8, imgData);

LOGPALETTE logpal=(LOGPALETTE)new BYTE[sizeof(LOGPALETTE)+256*sizeof(PALETTEENTRY)];
logpal.palVersion=0x300;
logpal.palNumEntries=256;
int i=0;
do {  //no idea your palette's format, however it looks to be greyscale?
    logpal->mypal[i].peRed=i;
    logpal->mypal[i].peGreen=i;
    logpal->mypal[i].peBlue=i;
    logpal->mypal[i].peFlags=NULL;
while(++i<256);
HPALETTE hPal=CreatePalette(logpal);

//If your trying to display it to a window's DC called mywindowsDC
HDC hBmpDC = CreateCompatibleDC(mywindowsDC);
SelectObject(hBmpDC, hBmp);
SelectPalette(hBmpDC, hPal, TRUE);
BitBlt(mywindowsDC, 0, 0, width, height, hBmpDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
RealizePalette(mywindowsDC);
//clean up
DeleteDC(hBmpDC);
delete [](BYTE *)logpal;
DeleteObject(hPal);
DeleteObject(hBmp);
```

Comment: I got your code to run, but nothing was drawn to screen.  Which one of those objects/handles you create contains the bytes I would need to create a .bmp file?

Comment: Sorry, code was untested, error is probably in the palette portion.
 Do you want to draw into a window or output it to a file? if you just want to output to a file without displaying it, there are a few simple functions out there for writing raw data to .bmp.

Comment: I want to write it to a file. I've seen lots of potential functions, but I'm not sure which of your objects holds the raw data I want. Do you want me to post your code with my modifications so it compiles?

Answer (score -2):

I would not read in the image data using `FILE*` operations: you can make it work, but it's verbose and prone to problems like `fread()` thinking a Ctrl-Z means End-of-File, plus you have to remember to close the file when you're finished. Instead I'd use the MFC `CFile` class. This will look something like

```
 BYTE* pbyImageData = NULL;
CFile fileImage;
if(fileImage.Open(_T("\\rawimage.dat"), CFile::modeRead, NULL))
{
     pbyImageData = new BYTE[fileImage.GetLength()];
     fileImage.Read(pbyImageData, fileImage.GetLength());
}
```

Bitmaps are easily handled in Windows CE using the `CDIBSectionCE` class. This is available from CodeGuru (['A DIBSection wrapper for Win32 and WinCE'](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/ce/bitmapsandthegdi/print.php/c3)). Using CDIBSectionCE, you would do something like this...

```
// The BITMAPINFO struct is almost completely unusable because it has
// space for a less-than-generous 1-colour palette, so I always end up
// creating a home-grown version with room for 256 colours:
struct BITMAPINFO256
{
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader;
    RGBQUAD          bmiColors[256];
} stcBmpInfo;

// ...Fill in the BITMAPINFO structure -- bitmap size etc.
stcBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
stcBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = .... 
/// etc ... keep the code you have for filling in bitmap info at present

// Now load up the image into the DIB Section
CDIBSectionCE bmp;
bmp.SetBitmap((BITMAPINFO*)&stcBmpInfo, pbyImageData);

// Now write the bitmap out as a file
bmp.Save(_T("\\mybitmap.bmp");
```

Note that `CDIBSectionCE` handles all the file header stuff. All you need to do is read in the image data, shovel it into a DIB Section, and then ask it to save itself out as a bitmap file.