# How to save bitmap to file using MFC on Windows CE 2013

Tags: c++, bitmap, mfc, save, windows-ce

I am looking for way to save bitmap to .bmp file using MFC.
Until I was looking for some informations in internet I get to known that Save method from CImage class is most popular way. Unfortunatelly in Windows CE MFC IDE this method is not avaliable for CImage class.
Have you know any another way to save CBitmap object to .bmp file?

Comment: I assume you can use the [Windows Imaging Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/gg158899(v=winembedded.80)).

Comment: This article may be helpful. [How to create a .bmp in WinCE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/441599/9014308)